# Maximal Information Coefficient vs Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering

Tags: functional-programming, duplicates, cluster-analysis, coefficients, information-theory

What is the difference between the Maximal Information Coefficient and Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering in identifying functional and non functional dependencies.

Which of them can identify duplicates better?

Comment: This should probably be moved to [stats.SE].

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make a lot of sense, sorry.

The MIC and HAC have close to zero in common.

The MIC is a crippled form of "correlation" with a very crude heuristic search, and plenty of promotion video and news announcements, and received some pretty harsh reviews from statisticians. You can file it in the category "**if it had been submitted to an appropriate journal** (rather than the quite  unspecific and overrated [Science which probably shouldn't publish such topics at all](http://simplystatistics.tumblr.com/post/16520282447/when-should-statistics-papers-be-published-in) - or at least, get better reviewers from the subject domains. It's not the first Science article of this quality....), **it would have been rejected** (as-is - better expert reviewers would have demanded major changes)". See, e.g.,

> Noah Simon and Robert Tibshirani, Comment on “Detecting Novel Associations in Large Data Sets” by Reshef et al., Science Dec. 16, 2011
>
> "As one can see from the Figure, MIC has lower power than dcor, in every case except the somewhat pathological high-frequency sine wave. MIC is sometimes less powerful than Pearson correlation as well, the linear case being particularly worrisome."

And "tibs" is a highly respected author. And this is just one of many surprised that such things get accepted in such a high reputation journal. IIRC, the MIC authors even failed to compare to "ancient" alternatives such as Spearman, to modern alternatives like dCor, or to properly conduct a test of statistical power of their method.

MIC works much worse than advertised when studied with statistical scrunity:

> Gorfine, M., Heller, R., & Heller, Y. (2012). Comment on "detecting novel associations in large data sets"
>
> "under the majority of the noisy functionals and non-functional settings, the HHG and dCor tests hold very large power advantages over the MIC test, under practical sample sizes; "

As a matter of fact, MIC gives wildly inappropriate results on some trivial data sets such as a checkerboard uniform distribution ▄▀, which it considers maximally correlated (as correlated as y=x); by design. Their grid-based design is overfitted to the rather special scenario with the sine curve. It has some interesting properties, but these are IMHO captured better by earlier approaches such as Spearman and dCor).

The failure by the MIC authors to compare to Spearman is IMHO a severe omission, because their own method is also purely rank-based if I recall correctly. Spearman is Pearson-on-ranks, yet they compare only to Pearson. The favorite example of MIC (another questionable choice) is the sine wave - which after rank transformation actually is busy a zigzag curve, not a sine anymore). I consider this to be "cheating" to make Pearson look bad, by not using the rank transformation with Pearson, too. Good reviewers would have demanded such a comparison.

Now all of these complaints are essentially unrelated to HAC. HAC is not trying to define any form if "correlation", but it can be used with any distance or similarity (including correlation similarity).
HAC is something completely different: a clustering algorithm. It analyzes a larger rows, not two (!) columns.

You could even combine them: if you compute the MIC foe every pair of variables (but I'd rather use Pearson correlation, Spearman correlation, or distance correlation dCor instead), you can use HAC to cluster variables.

For finding aftual duplicates, neither is a good choice. Just sort your data, and duplicates will follow each other. (Or, if you sort columns, next to each other).